# How can I return Base Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I am creating new Application in Android Platform.

I'm Having trouble with returning the base Activity.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        setContentView(R.layout.setting_layout);
         ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
         //Return to Base
         actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I tried to change Manifest.xml with:

```
<application 
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
<activity...
<meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    android:value=".TestParentActivity">
</meta-data>
</activity>
```

etc..

However, these don't work.

Please help me.

Thank You.
Best Regards.

Comment: what do you mean return the base activity, return it to what?

Comment: To return MainActivity..

For example, If user clicks the settings, it will replace layout. However, user clicks action bar(return main) then it doesn't work.

Comment: you want to change the layout or go back to the `MainActivity`?

Comment: exactly, I want to change the layout or go back.

Comment: that is what I am asking, which one do you want to do

Comment: MainActivity. Sorry for my mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the up button id is `android.R.id.home`

so in your onOptionsItemSelected you need this

```
case android.R.id.home:
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    return true;
```

and in the activity in your manifest you need to declare a parent activity tag

```
android:parentActivityName
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work:

`<activity  android:name=".Setting"
            android:parentActivityName="MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_setting">  
                   
        </activity>` it is manifest.

Then it is for home button `if(id == R.id.home){
   NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
      return true;
  }`

Comment: You need the full path of your activity class

Comment: It has error with if(id == R.id.home) It doesn't called "home" I think. Because I tested with Toast message but it doesn't work.

Comment: Add following code in your onCreate() and then look for R.id.home                 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: You need android.r.id.home

Comment: Make sure your minSdkVersion is 11 or higher since home was introduced in 11.

Comment: @tyczj it works with android.R but Why we use android ? I don't understand

Comment: Because it is an android resource id

Answer (score 1):

Try using android:ParentActivityName:".MainActivity" in your   tag

Beginning in Android 4.1 (API level 16), you can declare the logical parent of each activity by specifying the android:parentActivityName attribute in the  element.

If your app supports Android 4.0 and lower, include the Support Library with your app and add a  element inside the . Then specify the parent activity as the value for android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY, matching the android:parentActivityName attribute.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

For more details about the ActionBar Naviagation read [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)